# Change cursor in window caption

Tags: c#, winforms, pinvoke, wndproc

I have a WinForm and now I need to change the cursor when it's in the windows caption part. I have some code working, it has 2 problems:

1. <strike>It also changes the cursor when on the edges (normal resize cursor should be shown).
   I found out the I need something like this `WM_NCHITTEST` & `HTTOP`, but how do I combine that?</strike>
2. There's some flicker when moving the mouse.

I also tried placing the code below the `base.WndProc(ref m);`.

This is the code I already have:

```
if ((m.Msg == Win32.WM.NCMOUSEMOVE
    || m.Msg == Win32.WM.NCLBUTTONDOWN || m.Msg == Win32.WM.NCLBUTTONUP
    || m.Msg == Win32.WM.NCRBUTTONDOWN || m.Msg == Win32.WM.NCRBUTTONUP)
)
{
    if (m.WParam.ToInt32() != Win32.HT.TOP && m.WParam.ToInt32() != Win32.HT.RIGHT && m.WParam.ToInt32() != Win32.HT.BOTTOM && m.WParam.ToInt32() != Win32.HT.LEFT)
    {
        Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
I wasn't logging the message correctly in Spy++. Found the solution to the window edges (see updated code).

Thnx, J

Comment: What about faking the window caption part? just a thought.

Comment: I have extended the window caption part to bellow, to allow glass transparency. On top of that I have drawn something, but I can't figure out how to correctly change the mouse cursor on the whole caption.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It flickers because you use the wrong message.  Any mouse move is followed by WM_SETCURSOR to allow the app to change the cursor.  So the cursor changes back to the default.  Intercept WM_SETCURSOR instead.  The low word of LParam contains the hit test code.

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        if (m.Msg == 0x20) {  // Trap WM_SETCUROR
            if ((m.LParam.ToInt32() & 0xffff) == 2) { // Trap HTCAPTION
                Cursor.Current = Cursors.Hand;
                m.Result = (IntPtr)1;  // Processed
                return;
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

Comment: Thnx. Aldo this fixes the flicker I was having, this does enable the other 'bug' partly. Only the top and topleft resize cursor is shown.

Comment: That seems to have very little to do with the snippet you posted. I'm getting good resize cursors on all edges and corners with the snippet that I posted.  Testing the hit test code is essential, the edges and corners have a different hit code, it won't be 2.

Comment: Sorry was my fault in converting it. Thank you for the answer